# Table View Sizing with Programatic Constraints

Tags: ios, swift, tableview, constraints

I'm having a bit of trouble with programatic constraints for my `UITableView`.

I have got the width correct but not the height as I also have a small bar on the top of the page which is just a coloured `UIView`. So I want to make it so the table view starts exactly at the bottom of the bar but also has constraints for the entire screen.

Here is my code for the `tableView`,

```
tableView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.frame.width, height: self.view.frame.height - 110)
tableView.center = CGPoint(x: self.view.center.x, y: self.view.center.y + 20)
```

So the `tableView` aligns with the top bar but now doesn't reach the bottom of the screen.
Any help?

More Code:

```
     //Top Bar
    topBar.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.frame.width, height: 150)
    topBar.center = CGPoint(x: self.view.center.x, y: self.view.frame.minY)
    topBar.backgroundColor = UIColor.init(fromHexCode: "1462BF")
    view.addSubview(topBar)
```

Comment: First of all, Are you using Auto layout Constraints?

Comment: I am using programatic constraints, not the ones on the main storyboard

Comment: Then show those programmatic constraints

Comment: If you are using frame that means not using AutoLayout. Set translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false on your views and apply constraints

Comment: this works by itselfs
        tableView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 75, width: self.view.frame.width, height: self.view.frame.height)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using Auto layout(`NSLayoutConstraint`), no need to frame or center to your tableView.

If you don't use Auto layout, you should frame your tableView as like below:

```
tableView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: heightOfYourSmallBar, width: self.view.frame.width, height: self.view.frame.height - heightOfYourSmallBar)
```

Comment: I tried this but it made the tableview go too far down the page

Comment: If you did set above frame, no need to set `tableView.center`.

Comment: i di get rid of the tableView.center

Comment: I guess, you are using both `NSLayoutConstraint` and frame to position your tableView. If so show your programatic constraints code.

Comment: so the code which made it fit the whole screen is:      tableView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.frame.width, height: self.view.frame.height)                                                                                          But I want it to fit the screen but just come down a small bit from the top to where the topBar ends

Comment: it works when I do tableView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 75, width: self.view.frame.width, height: self.view.frame.height)

Comment: So `heightOfYourSmallBar` is 65? or Are you referring nav bar as small bar?

Comment: well I set the height to 150 but the height for the tableView which it works at and is all good is 75 which is half that

Answer (score 0):

Setting the frame and the center is not enough, because your view's frame might change when the view controller is pushed/presented. What you should do is to use layout constraints. I find Layout Anchors to be the easiest way of programmatically creating constraints

```
tableView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
tableView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topBar.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
tableView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
tableView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
tableView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
```

As you can see, your `tableView` top anchor is aligned to your `topBar` bottom anchor, and other tableView's constraints are aligned to view's leading, trailing and bottom.

Comment: tableView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topBar.bottomAnchor).isActive = true .   this line stuffs it up

Comment: Care to elaborate? When, what's the message? And of course at the time of creating constraints `tableView` must be a subview of `view` and `topBar` must be a part of the same view hierarchy - let's say also a subview of `view`. You cannot create constraints before all views that are part of them are initialized and added to view hierarchy

Comment: well I have a home page and when I click the button to get to this page, it crashes and tells me SIGABRT. what do you mean subview?

Comment: Show more code - how and where you are creating the views and the constraints

Comment: I added the top bar code (which is a UIView variable I made in the viewDidLoad)

Answer (score 0):

If you're using `AutoLayout` then setting frames will not work, just set proper constraints to position `UITableView` in `UIViewController`

1. set `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false` for tableView to use AutoLayout
2. Apply constraints to position and view

   ```
   enter code heretableView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

   NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
       tableView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor),
       tableView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor),
       tableView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor),
       tableView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor, constant: -110)
   ])
   ```